# Is there a way to prevent a descendant thread from getting into cgroup of its ancestor thread automatically?

Tags: cgroups, multithreading, pthreads

I write some threads of my app to a Linux `cpu` cgroup, created by me, explicitly (let us talk e.g. about v1 for now, but if you know a way for v2, that would be also great).

However, I see that descendant threads (created with `pthread_create()` called by their parent thread, which is written to the cgroup explicitly or again after its parent thread) also appear in the cgroup without me writing them directly.

This affects the app not in a good way. Some threads get to the cgroup unexpectedly. You need be always aware of this caveat and be careful e.g. with thread pools etc.

Could you, please, tell if there is a way to solve this problem? E.g., maybe is there a way to forbid descendant threads from getting into their parent's cgroup automatically? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why is it "unexpected"? Where do you expect the threads to be created? Threads and children are always automatically created at the cgroup of the parent. For the memory cgroup subsystem I don't think it's even possible to have threads of the same pid in different cgroups, because they all share the same memory space.

Comment: I meant cpu cgroup, sorry, I've updated my question. @aviro

Answer (score 1):

In the man pages of [`clone(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) you can find information about the flag `CLONE_INTO_CGROUP`:

> ```
>    CLONE_INTO_CGROUP (since Linux 5.7)
>           By default, a child process is placed in the same version
>           2 cgroup as its parent.  The CLONE_INTO_CGROUP flag allows
>           the child process to be created in a different version 2
>           cgroup.  (Note that CLONE_INTO_CGROUP has effect only for
>           version 2 cgroups.)
>
>           In order to place the child process in a different cgroup,
>           the caller specifies CLONE_INTO_CGROUP in cl_args.flags
>           and passes a file descriptor that refers to a version 2
>           cgroup in the cl_args.cgroup field.  (This file descriptor
>           can be obtained by opening a cgroup v2 directory using
>           either the O_RDONLY or the O_PATH flag.)  Note that all of
>           the usual restrictions (described in cgroups(7)) on
>           placing a process into a version 2 cgroup apply.
> ```

There's more information below in the man page.

However, `pthread_create` is just a wrapper to `clone`, that uses a defined set of [flags](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/nptl/pthread_create.c.html#277) that cannot be changed:

```
  const int clone_flags = (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SYSVSEM
               | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD
               | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID
               | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
               | 0);
```

So it seems to me the only way to achieve your goal is to use `clone` instead of `pthread_create`. I personally never tried it, but it seems like your best shot.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you! I upvote. Alas, I cannot use the approach. I have to use a library that manages the creation of threads.